# How to set output from findstr to a variable

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set result=""
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in ('FINDSTR /I /S /C:"A=1" C:\Users\Family\Desktop\saxcz find.bat') 
do set result=%%i
)
  echo !result!
) else (
  echo xx
)
pause>nul
```

is my code but the output is

C:\Users\Family\Desktop\saxcz\find.bat:set
xx

why is this happening?

Comment: You have an `else` in your code... Where is the belonging `if`-statement?

Comment: and the closing parenthesis in front of `echo !result!`? also seems there's a missing backslash in the filename

Comment: `do` cannot be on a separate line, it must be on the same line as the preceding closing `)`! Read this: [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: You are looking for _A=1_ or _a=1_ from what? The output you have provided is not consistent with the search criteria. At first I thought you had just accidentally replaced a backslash for a space, but if that was the case could you please tell us the purpose of the **/S** option you have passed to FINDSTR?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the task you try to achieve, but this may help

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "result="
set/a offset=0

for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=:" %%i in ('FINDSTR /N /I /S /C:"A=1" C:\Users\Family\Desktop\saxcz\find.bat') do (
   set/a offset+=1 & set "line=0000%%i" 
   set "result[!offset!]=!line:~-4! %%j"
)

if %offset% neq 0 (
  echo( 
  echo(Line  data 
  echo(----  --------------------------------- 
  for /L %%i in (1,1,%offset%) do echo(!result[%%i]!
  echo(--------------------------------------- 
  echo( 
  echo( %offset% items found
) else (
  echo(Not found
)
endlocal
exit/B
```